# Match Schedule Generator Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, jsp, scheduling

I'm working on a schedule generator where every team plays a match with each other teams. My Database table and the output I need like below,
[image]

What I have tried so far is

```
 <%
    ResultSet rsteams = clmmodel_database.selectQuery("select count(ct.teamid) as teamcount, teamid,teamname from clm_team ct");
    while(rsteams.next()){
       int teamcount = rsteams.getInt("teamcount"); 
       int n = teamcount - 1;
       int numofmatches  = n*(n+1)/2; 
    %>
    <h1>Team Count = <%out.print(teamcount);%></h1>
    <h1>Number of Matches = <%out.print(numofmatches);%></h1>
    <table>
    <%for(int i =0;i<n;i++){%>
    <tr>
      //Here I need to display the matches row by row  
    </tr>
    <%}%>
    </table>

    <%}%>
```

Which retrieves the team count and the number of matches to be played. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible solution:

```
<%for(int i =0; i< n - 1; i++){%>
  <%for(int j = i + 1; i<n; j++){%>
    <tr>
      //Here you can display team i and team j
    </tr>
  <%}%> 
<%}%>
```

I also suggest you to look at [these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament#Scheduling_algorithm) algorithms.

Comment: How can I retrieve two values from two rows at once? since the two team ids and names are in two rows

Comment: You can use ResultSet.absolut method (the index begins at 1) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#absolute(int)